# Express.js: Match route in catch all

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Can one check a `express.js` route against multiple patterns? Consider the catch all `*` route below.`req.route` is matched to `*` here. I'd like to check the route against a few special scenarios within the same callback ~ NOT inside another `all` or `use` middleware.

```
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  // How do I check if route is a special case like below
  if(req.route in ['/foo/:param', '/bar/:param']){}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're dismissing separate `.all` routes for this, because it seems to me to be the best way of performing these checks:

```
app.all('/foo/:param', (req, res, next) => {
  req.isFoo = true;
  next();
});

app.all('/bar/:param', (req, res, next) => {
  req.isBar = true;
  next();
});

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isFoo || req.isBar) { ... }
})
```

Or, analogous to Chris's answer, have one route to match both:

```
app.all([ '/foo/:param', '/bar/:param' ], (req, res, next) => {
  req.isSpecial = true;
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. This is what I'll end up doing. Was hoping for a `express.matches` like ability to avoid yet another `all` route.

Comment: @AnshulKoka there are modules that you could use (like  [`path-to-from-params`](https://github.com/dhoulb/path-to-from-params)), but I think having separate `app.all()` handlers is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

So you should not try to use the wildcard to capture everything than look for specific values.   Instead, create an endpoint that looks for these specific values and then use another route for the capture all wildcard.

```
app.get(['/test', '/another_value'], (req, res, next) => {

})
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I need to check this inside a `catch-all` like my code suggests. My `catch-all` needs to perform authentication but ignore a few paths.